# Installing cuda and cudnn in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and installed nvidia driver. Graphics card using is Nvidia Geforce MX130. I want to use tensorflow gpu features for my application to run. When I checked nvidia driver status using `nvidia-smi` i can see that CUDA 11.4 is installed. But I cannot access it.

[image: nvidia-smi result]

`nvcc -v` is not returning anything.
When I execute

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

I am getting the following message

```
2021-10-24 01:01:23.589474: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:23.589501: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-10-24 01:01:27.116341: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-10-24 01:01:27.152883: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153253: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153313: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153365: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153414: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153464: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153516: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153567: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153618: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-10-24 01:01:27.153633: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Please install GPU version of TF
```

How to make this work in a perfect clean way.

NB: Please upvote the question so that I will get few privileges from stackoverflow

Thanks in Advance

Comment: CUDA is not installed.  See:  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-showing-different-cuda-version-after-installation/183213/3 that just means that it supports API activity up through version 11.4.

Comment: None of the libcu* files are there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install NVIDIA and CUDA drivers into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu)  I just updated this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142 for CUDA 11.5 installation.

Comment: As per my understanding  nvidia-smi shows CUDA 11.4 will be supported by my nvidia driver. So will there be any problem to occur when CUDA 11.5 is compiled

Comment: The samples appear to work fine where the driver shows 11.4 but running 11.5